# How to use a forked version of cordova-android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-android

There's a problem with the current version of cordova-android that doesn't allow you to have a "&" symbol in the name of your app.

I forked a fix of a pull request I found on the repo.

I changed my package.json from

`"cordova-android": "^10.1.1",`

to

`"cordova-android":https://github.com/fitdegree/cordova-android.git",`

but now when I run `cordova platform add android`

I get the following error message:

```
cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@https://github.com/fitdegree/cordova-android.git
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@https://github.com/fitdegree/cordova-android.git
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 127 Error output:
```

any ideas on how I can use my forked version?

Answer (score 1):

`cordova platform add` uses NPM behind the scenes, so any valid npm install package will work.

##### cordova platform add <git url>

e.g: `cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git`

##### cordova platform add ../local-path

e.g: `cordova platform add ../path/to/my-cordova-android-fork`

##### cordova platform add cordova-android.tgz

Pack up the cordova-android package using `npm pack`, which produces a `tgz` file. Then use `cordova platform add my-cordova-android.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

Read its [guides](https://github.com/fitdegree/cordova-android):

After creating app as usual, link the forked android platform using:

```
cordova platform add --link /path/to/cordova-android
```

Down the forked release via [this link](https://github.com/fitdegree/cordova-android/releases/tag/10.1.1)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however this doesn't work for me. It says Local modules not found. Try running npm install. I've run npm install in both the cordova-android repo on my local computer & the app. Could have to do with me using a mono repo?